# String replacement with multiple string

Tags: php

I have a message template where i need to replace the set of strings, for example

I have a message:

> You have been invited by the [ADMIN_NAME] of the Organization
>   [ORGANIZATION_NAME] on [DATETIME]

Needs to be replaced by `ADMIN_NAME`, `ORGANIZATION_NAME`, `DATETIME`

Comment: just make an array and concatenate values to the string. $email = array("adminName"=>"SO Admin", "OrganizationName"=>"Stack Overflow","dateTime"=>"tomorrow 10:00 pm");  $string = "You have been invited by the $email['adminName'] of the Organization $email['OrganizationName'] on $email['dateTime']";

Answer (score 2):

Use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$text = 'You have been invited by the [ADMIN_NAME] of the Organization [ORGANIZATION_NAME] on [DATETIME]';

$result = strtr($text, [
    '[ADMIN_NAME]' => 'Some name',
    '[ORGANIZATION_NAME]' => 'Some organization',
    '[DATETIME]' => 'some date',
]);

echo $result;
```

Output:

> You have been invited by the Some name of the Organization Some organization on some date

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$from = array('[ADMIN_NAME]','[ORGANIZATION_NAME]','[DATETIME]');
$to = array('ADMIN_NAME','ORGANIZATION_NAME','DATETIME');
$message = 'You have been invited by the [ADMIN_NAME] of the Organization [ORGANIZATION_NAME] on [DATETIME]';
echo str_replace($from,$to,$message);
```

Add the template variables in the first array, and the values in the second array

And use the str_replace function after doing that