# replace parts of a string with a vector

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I am having problems with replacing parts of a single string with a set of vector replacements, to result in a vector.

I have a string `tex` which is intended to tell a diagram what text to put as the node (and other) labels.

So if `tex` is `"!label has frequency of !frequency"`
and `T` has columns `label` with values `c("chickens","ducks",...)` and `frequency`  with values `c("chickens","ducks",...)` amongst others,
the function returns a vector like `c("Chickens has frequency of 35","Ducks has frequency of 12",...)`

More formally, the problem is:

Given a tibble `T` and a string `tex`,
return a vector with length `nrow(T)`, of which each element = `tex` but in which each occurrence within `tex` of the pattern `!pattern` is replaced by the vectorised contents of `T$pattern`

I looked at 
[Replace string in R with patterns and replacements both vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301218/replace-string-in-r-with-patterns-and-replacements-both-vectors)
and
[String replacement with multiple string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831478/string-replacement-with-multiple-string) but they don't fit my usecase.
stringr::str_replace() doesn't do it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible baseR-solution using `sprintf()`

```
animals = c("chickens","ducks") 
frequency = c(35,12)

sprintf( "%s has frequency of %s", animals, frequency)
```

> [1] "chickens has frequency of 35" "ducks has frequency of 12"

also,

```
tex = "%s has frequency of %s"
sprintf( tex, animals, frequency )
```

will gave the same results.